# Why M = L + ((R - L) / 2) instead of M=(L+R)/2 avoid overflow in C++?

Tags: c++

Hello I was looking at the C++ solution to the question "Suppose a sorted array is rotated at some pivot unknown to you beforehand. (i.e., 0 1 2 4 5 6 7 might become 4 5 6 7 0 1 2). How do you find an element in the rotated array efficiently? You may assume no duplicate exists in the array."

```
int rotated_binary_search(int A[], int N, int key) {
    int L = 0;
    int R = N - 1;

    while (L <= R) {
    // Avoid overflow, same as M=(L+R)/2
        int M = L + ((R - L) / 2);
        if (A[M] == key) return M;

    // the bottom half is sorted
        if (A[L] <= A[M]) {
            if (A[L] <= key && key < A[M])
                R = M - 1;
            else
                L = M + 1;
        }
    // the upper half is sorted
        else {
            if (A[M] < key && key <= A[R])
                L = M + 1;
            else 
                R = M - 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

and saw the comment says that using M = L + ((R - L) / 2) instead of M=(L+R)/2 avoid overflow. Why is that? Thx ahead

Comment: Play around with some large values for `M` and `L`, you'll figure this out for yourself quite quickly.  Then you can look forward to answering this sort of question on SO and bathe in glory.

Comment: http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html (the sort routines have been fixed by now)

Comment: Note that this doesn't avoid overflow for cases where `L` or `R` can be negative, because then `R-L` can overflow too. You need to jump through some surprisingly wordy hoops to get a safe, general integer average.

Comment: It's Bentley's Bug. (only someone as accomplished as Bentley can have a bug named after him, without it being a stigma).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Because it does...

Let's assume for a minute you're using unsigned chars (same applies to larger integers of course).

If L is 100 and R is 200, the first version is:

```
M = (100 + 200) / 2 = 300 / 2 = 22
```

100+200 overflows (because the largest unsigned char is 255), and you get 100+200=44 (unsigned no. addition).

The second, on the other hand:

```
M = 100 + (200-100) / 2 = 100 + 100 / 2 = 150
```

No overflow.

As @user2357112 pointed out in a comment, there are no free lunches. If L is negative, the second version might not work while the first will.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure, but if the max limit of int is suppose 100.

```
R=80 & L = 40
then, 
M=(L+R)/2
M=(120)/2, here 120 is out limits if our integer type, so this causes overflow
```

However,

```
M = L + ((R - L) / 2)  
M = 80 +((40)/2)
M = 80 +20
M =100.
```

So in this case we never encounter a value that exceeds the limits of our integer type.So this approach will never encounter a overFlow, THEORATICALLY.

I hope this analogy will help

Comment: Except that you placed 80 for L, everything else is valid. :P

Answer (score 1):

The comment is wrong, for a number of reasons.

- For the particular problem the risk of overflow is probably nil.
- Reordering calculations does not guarantee that the compiler will perform them in that order.
- If there is a range of values for which an ordering can cause overflow, then there is another range of values for which the reordered calculation will cause overflow.
- If overflow could be a problem then it should be controlled explicitly, not implicitly.

This is an excellent place for an assert. In this case the algorithm is only valid if `N` is less than half the maximum positive range of `int`, so say it in an assert.

If the algorithm is required to work for the whole positive range of `signed int` then the range should be explicitly tested in an assert, and the calculation should be ordered by introducing a sequence point (eg broken into two statements).

Doing this right is hard. Numerical computation is full of this stuff. Best to avoid, if possible. And don't accept random advice (even this!) without doing your own research.

Answer (score 1):

It avoids overflow in this specific implementation, which operates under the guarantees that `L` and `R` are non-negative and `L <= R`. Under these guarantees it should be obvious that `R - L` does not overflow and `L + ((R - L) / 2)` does not overflow either.

In general case (i.e. for arbitrary values of `L` and `R`) `R - L` is as prone to overflow as `L + R`, meaning that this trick does not achieve anything.